# Orchard not saving custom type items

Tags: orchardcms

I've created a new content type, product.

And a products List.

When I save a new Product item, and select Products from the list, Orchard tells me that the product have been saved correctly, but oddly the [Add to] combo box turns back to None, and the Product isn't really saved anywhere.

If I list the items for the Product type, I see nothing.
If I go to the Products page on the site, the content is empty.

What do I do wrong? 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't add the `Common` content part. Now all works well.

Comment: no, I cannot before two days since I submitted the question. As soon as I can, I will.